# Help with SQL query (add 5% to users with conditions)

Tags: sql, mysql

I’m having some difficulties with a query which purpose is to give users with more than one thread (called CS) in current year a 5% point “raise”.
My relational schema looks like this:

```
Thread = (**threadid**, threadname, threadLocation)

threadoffering = (threadid, season, year, user)

user = (**name**, points)
```

Then, what I need is to check:

```
WHERE thread.threadid = threadoffering.threadid AND where threadoffering.year AND threadoffering.season = currentDate AND where threadoffering.User > 1
```

then GIVE 5 % raise TO user.points

I hope it is explained thoroughly but otherwise here it is in short text:

Give a 5 % “point raise” to all users who has more than 1 thread in threadLocation CS in the current year and season (always dynamic, so for example now is year = 2010 and season is = spring).

I am looking forward to your answer

Sincerely,
Emil

Comment: What is your definition of different seasons? I presume you mean spring in the Northern hemisphere? Is it... Spring: March, April and May
Summer: June, July, August
Autumn: September, October, November
Winter: December, January, February

Comment: Also how is the User table related to threadoffering?

Comment: Hey Martin,

the system is designed for students where they can help each other so season is like term: There is SPRING and there is FALL, and I guess that the SPRING is from February to July and the FALL is from August to January

Comment: You still haven't answered my Question above. Also what is the PK of the threadoffering table? It looks like it should be all 4 columns. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT
    u.name,
    CASE WHEN (COUNT(*) > 1)
        THEN MIN(u.points) * 1.05
        ELSE MIN(u.points)
    END AS points
FROM
    threadoffering to inner join user u
        on to.user = u.name
WHERE
    to.year = @targetYear and to.season = @targetSeason
GROUP BY
    u.name
```

Comment: From the OP's WHERE clause threadoffering.user is numeric so I assume they have tried to simplify the DDL and left out a vital bit. Also I thought they wanted an UPDATE query?

Comment: Good point about the numeric usage in the WHERE clause... if that is the case, then this schema is awful. Also, the update would be very destructive, but this query above could be used to determine what to update to.